# Query doesn't work via php script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple php script which performs a simple SQL query twice. Query works perfectly for the first but for the second time error appears;

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\apache\localhost\www\study.kg\webstore\web_store.php on line 48
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function free() on a non-object in C:\apache\localhost\www\study.kg\webstore\web_store.php on line 80

First, we make a query to 'categories' table. Everything is good.
Second, we make the same query to 'shoes' table. Everything is bad, because

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM shoes";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

returns `FALSE` value.

But why? The first it worked perfectly. The tables are the same, if you mean encoding and etc. So, as you can guess, my first table displays itself perfectly, second table doesn't show any data at all.
Here is a full snippet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Лабораторная: интернет-магазин обуви</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
@$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'dzhakipov', 'asd12345', 'webshop');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: could not connect to database. Please try again later.';
    exit;
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$result = $db->query($query);

$num_results = $result->num_rows;

?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>id</td>
        <td>Название</td>
        <td>Описание</td>
        <td>Поставщик</td>
        <td>Продавец</td>
        <td>Адрес склада</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['id']). "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['name'])). "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['description']). "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['supplier']). "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['salesman']). "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['storage_address']). "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM shoes";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    $num_results = $result->num_rows; // LINE 48 #############################
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>id</td>
            <td>categoryid</td>
            <td>Название</td>
            <td>Пол</td>
            <td>Размер</td>
            <td>Сезон</td>
            <td>Внешний материал</td>
            <td>Внутренний материал</td>
            <td>Цвет</td>
            <td>Описание</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['id']). "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['categoryid']). "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($row['name'])). "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['sex']). "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['size']). "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['season']). "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['inner_material']). "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['outer_material']). "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['colour']). "</td>";
            echo "<td>" .stripslashes($row['price']). "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        $result->free(); // LINE 80 #############################
        $db->close();
        ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for attention.

Comment: If you connect to the database and run the second query (`SELECT * FROM shoes`) do you get any rows? If not, then that's your problem.

Comment: The problem is that I don't get anything from the query. In case of sucess mysqli_query() returns mysqli_result object. In case of failure it returns FALSE. What is wrong with my query?

Comment: I've always coded to allow for no resultset (i.e. a `false` from `mysqli_query()`) if there are no rows to return. If there is an error, then `mysqli_error()` will have a valid return.

Comment: There are rows in shoes table. Checked it via phpmyadmin and via mysql console.

Comment: So now you need to check what `mysqli_error()` says.

Comment: Oh my god, turns out I couldn't get any rows from the table because I had no privelegies to the table. Thank you for you help, now that I'm familiar with mysqli_error(), I swear to call to this function before asking stupid questions. I'll delete my question tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

See this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php before using result for the second time.

You also can change the second $result into $result2 to let It work.

Comment: Watchout, you're linking a procedural function which is part of the deprecated mysql connector. In mysqli's case, there's a static method for the mysqli_result object http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try freeing the first result before querying for the second

```
$result->free();
$query = "SELECT * FROM shoes";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

Second, though I'm not familiar with mysqli (big PDO fan here), I believe false might be a possible result of a query, so you should wrap the result traversing in an if block.

```
if($result) {
    $num_results = $result->num_rows;
    ...
    $result->free();
}
```

Comment: Didn't help either :(

Comment: There are rows in shoes table. Checked it via phpmyadmin and via mysql console.

Comment: what if you run the queries in inverse order. First shoes, then categories? Try also declaring different result variables for each, like $categoriesresult and $shoesresult (this was @Daniël van Rijn 's suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

As you store your MySQL query as a String in $Query variable now for the php to execute this query you need to use mysqli_query() that will retrieve data from DB